# Oraclize querying multiple API's in one call

Tags: solidity, oracles

I wonder if it's possible to call oraclize JUST ONCE, and get results from different APIs.

```
oraclize_query("URL" , "['json1' , 'json2']");
```

The problem that I have is that the API that I'm using does not allow to get two values from one call. Therefore I need to call it twice. So I wonder if I can call oraclize one time and get those two values.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I wonder if can can call oraclize one time and get those two values.

You can call oraclize query once and send two inputs, **but** unfortunatelly you can call only one API.

I will list below all the queries available in Oraclize API at the moment.

---

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract OraclizeI {
    function query(uint _timestamp, string _datasource, string _arg) external payable returns (bytes32 _id);
    function query_withGasLimit(uint _timestamp, string _datasource, string _arg, uint _gaslimit) external payable returns (bytes32 _id);
    function query2(uint _timestamp, string _datasource, string _arg1, string _arg2) public payable returns (bytes32 _id);
    function query2_withGasLimit(uint _timestamp, string _datasource, string _arg1, string _arg2, uint _gaslimit) external payable returns (bytes32 _id);
    function queryN(uint _timestamp, string _datasource, bytes _argN) public payable returns (bytes32 _id);
    function queryN_withGasLimit(uint _timestamp, string _datasource, bytes _argN, uint _gaslimit) external payable returns (bytes32 _id);
}
```

---

[Source](https://github.com/oraclize/ethereum-api/blob/master/oraclizeAPI_0.5.sol)

Comment: It's too bad this isn't in the official docs right now